# removeChild from another Module

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild, dom-events

I'm trying to remove a childNode when set time expires. When the countdown reaches 0. I want to remove the button that submits the answer, stopping the player to submit answer. The button is created in another Module than the timer and that seems to be a problem. Is there a way to remove the childNode(button) or is there another way to kill the function of the button somehow?
Code from Module1

```
let answerDiv = document.querySelector('#answer')
let input = document.createElement('input')
input.type = 'text'
answerDiv.appendChild(input)


let button = document.createElement('button')
button.type = 'button'
button.setAttribute('id', 'button')
button.innerText = 'Answer'
answerDiv.appendChild(button)
```

Code from Module2

```
function timer () {
  let seconds = 21

  function countDown () {
    let counter = document.querySelector('#timer')
    seconds--
    counter.innerText = seconds.toString()
    if (seconds > 0) {
      setTimeout(countDown, 1000)
    }

    if (seconds === 0) {
      counter.innerText = 'Too slow!'
      let remove = document.querySelector('#button')
      remove.removeChild(remove)
    }
  }
  countDown()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to remove the `#button` from inside the your `#answer` container, so instead of:

```
if (seconds === 0) {
  counter.innerText = 'Too slow!'
  let remove = document.querySelector('#button')
  remove.removeChild(remove) // HERE YOU TRY TO REMOVE A NODE EXISTING INSIDE THE SAME NODE, THAT DOESN'T MAKE SENSE
}
```

do this:

```
if (seconds === 0) {
  counter.innerText = 'Too slow!'
  let answerDiv = document.querySelector('#answer')
  let remove = document.querySelector('#button')
  answerDiv.removeChild(remove)
}
```